# PHP hash_pbkdf2 to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I'm trying to convert the **hash_pbkdf2 of PHP** to javascript, but their output is not quite the same, I'm using the **crypto.pbkdf2Sync of javascript (nodejs)** for this.

*For this example, the password I've used is: "**password**"*

**PHP:**

```
$iv = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, strlen($password), 1000, 16);
echo "iv: " . $iv . "<br />";
echo "iv length: " . strlen($iv);
```

> **Output**: 
> **iv**: 4cf7620724f7b273
>   **iv length:** 16

**Javascript:**

```
var iv = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, password.length.toString(), 1000, 16, 'sha256');
console.log(iv.toString('hex'));
console.log(iv.length);
```

> **Output**: 
> **iv**: 4cf7620724f7b27347b7765889cf27e1
>   **iv length:** 16

It's very confusing because the output of javascript's pbkdf2 is longer (but you can see the first 16 letters is the same), **but their length is the same!** Am I missing something on this?

*Note:
I can't adjust the PHP code (because that's what they're using), I can only adjust my javascript code (for it to fit to them)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth argument to `hash_pbkdf2()` is `$length` (16, in your example), but it counts in *hexadecimal characters*, not bytes. To reproduce that result in Javascript, pass a length of 8, or trim the output to 16 characters after `.toString("hex")`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea sir, let me try the encryption again, hope it will be the same as the PHP. Thanks again sir :)